# Customizing UITableViewSectionHeader - Image vs Drawing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, custom-controls

I have to create my own Section Header View of a UITableView, with a border on top, on bottom, and a background color.

My question is, what's the best (or most correct) way to accomplish this?

- Using a image?
- Or drawing the borders and background color with Quartz 2D?
- Are there performance differences?

Thank you! (sorry by my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is borders and background color, then drawing them by would definitely be the way to go. Performance will be better if you draw them versus the image. Although `UIImages` are highly optimized in iPhone, still custom drawing will offer better performance.

Comment: Tks! Based on your answer, I've decided to go with Quartz. Performance is a important issue on this project.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is probably using CALayers. Give your view the desired background color, and add two layers to act as your borders. Assuming you want single pixel borders an example (black borders, white background) would be:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 24)];
headerView.backgroundCoor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CALayer *topLine = [CALayer layer];
topLine.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1);
topLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[headerView.layer addSublayer:topLine];

// repeat for bottom line
```

Another way would be to use the borderColor/borderWidth properties on the view layer, but then you need to perform some tricks (masking or sizing the view too wide) to hide the side borders.

Layers are quite powerful, you can add gradients, shapes and masks easily without messing around with CG drawing.

Comment: Tks! The use of gradients with CALayer will probably help me a lot on this project.